# how to compile python kivy app for ios on Windows 10 using buildozer?

Tags: python, ios, kivy, buildozer

I succesfully compiled app for android, and now I want to compile python kivy app for ios using buildozer. My operation system is Windows 10, so I don't know how to compile file for ios. I downloaded ubuntu console from microsoft store, that helped me to compile apk file. How to compile file for ios? I hope you help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can only deploy to iOS if you're working on a MacOS machine.

Comment: can i use a virtual machine or something like that?

Comment: can you help me with my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360841/kivy-ios-toolchain-py-line-4-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-mac-high