# kivy-ios .toolchain.py: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file in Mac High Sierra

Tags: python, ios, macos, kivy

I try to compile python file to ios file on mac. I used kivy-for-ios documentation. I executed:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config
brew link libtool
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install Cython==0.29.10

git clone git://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
cd kivy-ios
```

I also executed this line:

```
chmod +x ./toolchain.py
```

because before I got error:

```
-bash: .toolchain.py: Permission denied
```

then

```
./toolchain.py build kivy
```

the last string returns error:

```
|from: can not read /var/mail/kivy-ios.toolchain
  .toolchain.py: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

why does it happens and how to fix it? I use python 3.7.5 and I have xcode 10.0.

Comment: what's the output of `python --version`?

Comment: @Erik `python --version` returns `Python 2.7.10`, but if I enter: `python3 --version` it returns `Python 3.7.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `python3 ./toolchain.py build kivy`

When you just write `./toolchain.py build kivy` it tries to use your default python, which in this case is python2. The toolchain.py scripts requires python3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422703/ipaddress-py-raise-typeerrors-and-s-are-not-of-the-same-versiona-b

Comment: please, anwer, if you don't know, since I wait

Comment: No, i'm sorry, i don't know the answer to your next question. Try asking in the kivy discord channel